# Magento multiple carts per customer

Tags: magento

I'm looking for a magento 1.9 solution to give the customer the posibility to have more than one cart. 
I've seen this in some other b2b shops. 
If a customer adds a product to cart, he/she will be able to select the cart to add to. Later in checkout the customer can select which cart to checkout.

Has anyone ever seen something like this in magento?

Thank you